# add/remove elements of checkbox from the array of state object in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

When user click on the checkbox item it should be added to array. When unchecked it should be removed from array list.
conditions:
Maintain the array in the state object which contains the employmentType of the checked checkbox input elements
1.Whenever the employment type input checkbox is checked, that respective employment type id should be present in the array
2.And whenever the employment type input checkbox is unchecked, that respective employment type id should be removed from the array
3.Form the string using join() and use that string as a query parameter in jobsApiUrl
code:

```
const employmentTypesList = [
  {label: 'Full Time',
    employmentTypeId: 'FULLTIME',
  },
  {
    label: 'Part Time',
    employmentTypeId: 'PARTTIME',
  },
  {
    label: 'Freelance',
    employmentTypeId: 'FREELANCE',
  },
  {
    label: 'Internship',
    employmentTypeId: 'INTERNSHIP',
  },
]

class Jobs extends Component {
  state = {
    apiStatus: apiConstantStatus.initial,
    jobsList: [],
    searchInput: '',
    activeEmploymentId: '',
    activeSalaryId: '',
    employmentTypeListId: [], 
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getJobs()
  }

  getJobs = async () => {
    this.setState({apiStatus: apiConstantStatus.inProgress})
    const jwtToken = Cookies.get('jwt_token')
    const {employmentTypeListId, activeSalaryId, searchInput} = this.state

    // Need update Here
    const employmentType = employmentTypeListId.join(',')

    const apiUrl = `https://apis.ccbp.in/jobs? 
    employment_type=${employmentType}&minimum_package=${activeSalaryId}&search=${searchInput}`
    const options = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${jwtToken}`,
      },
      method: 'GET',
    }
}
}
export default Jobs

//render method

onChangeEmployTypesIds = event => {

    const {employmentTypeListId} = this.state
    const isChecked = event.target.checked
    console.log(isChecked)
    // add values to array
    if (isChecked) {
      this.setState({
        employmentTypeListId: [...employmentTypeListId, event.target.value],
      })
    } else {

      // remove item from array

      const filtered = employmentTypeListId.filter(
        eachItem => eachItem !== event.target.value,
      )
      this.setState({employmentTypeListId: filtered})
    }
}
renderEmploymentTypesList = () => {

const {activeEmploymentId} = this.state

    return employmentTypesList.map(empType => (
      <li key={empType.employmentTypeId} >
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          className="checkbox-input"
          id="emp"
          value={activeEmploymentId}
          onChange={this.onChangeEmployTypesIds}
        />
        <label htmlFor="emp" className="label-name" value="label">
          {empType.label}
        </label>
      </li>
    ))
}
```

Comment: Are you getting error with this code?

Comment: yes ,it not working actually.

Comment: When user click the checkbox it is not added to  array as I mentioned in state object and after that it should send as query parameter. Multiple checkbox elements should be added.

Comment: If possible, try to add a codesandbox of your code.